# Unusual crash while navigating between fragments using BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, xamarin.android, bottomnavigationview, fragmentmanager

I have a BottomNavigationView in my android activity, which consists of 4 menuItems. When I navigate between these fragments at times the app crashes with a null pointer exception. And in my AppCentes diagnostics section, it says the crash happened inside the FragmentManager. The exception is that there is a getClass() method call on a null object. Can anyone point out a reason that could be behind this behavior? Attaching the crash log.

[image]

The code for switching the fragments is mentioned below.

```
private void BottomNavigationItemSelected(object obj, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs args)
    {
        string title = "";
        if (args.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_explore)
        {
            title = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.shelf_title);
            fragment = _exploreFragment;
            _fragmentTag = "Home";
        }
        else
        {
            title = args.Item.TitleFormatted.ToString();
        }
        if (args.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_dashboard)
        {
            fragment = _redesignDashboard;
            _fragmentTag = "Dashboard";
        }
        else if (args.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_more)
        {
            fragment = _moreFragment;
            _fragmentTag = "More";
        }
        else if (args.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_report)
        {
            fragment = _reportFragment;
            _fragmentTag = "Report";
        }
        else if (args.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_downloads)
        {
            fragment = _downloadGalleryFragment;
            _fragmentTag = "Downloads";

        }
        if (fragment != null)
        {
            _toolbarTitle.Text = title;
            ToggleTitle(true);
            SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.fab_slide_in_from_right, Resource.Animation.fab_slide_out_to_left).Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment, _fragmentTag).Commit();
        }
    }
```

StackTrace for the same from MS AppCenter:

```
JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args)
JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms)
FragmentTransactionInvoker.Replace (System.Int32 containerViewId, Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment, System.String tag)
BookshelfActivity.BottomNavigationItemSelected (System.Object obj, Android.Support.Design.Widget.BottomNavigationView+NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs args)
BottomNavigationView+IOnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor.OnNavigationItemSelected (Android.Views.IMenuItem item)
BottomNavigationView+IOnNavigationItemSelectedListenerInvoker.n_OnNavigationItemSelected_Landroid_view_MenuItem_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_item)
(wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.26(intptr,intptr,intptr)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:392)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:439)
mono.android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor.n_onNavigationItemSelected(Native Method)
mono.android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor.onNavigationItemSelected(BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemSelectedListenerImplementor.java:30)
android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:182)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView$1.onClick(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:95)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26211)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your fragments are being garbage collected by Android which is causing this issue.

You shouldn't hold references to your fragments in order to switch tabs. The FragmentManager has a caching mechanism built in which you can take advantage of.

You are already tagging your fragments. You can use that to find cached fragmented inside the fragment manager and if its null, create a new one:

```
var cachedFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
if (cachedFragment == null){
    cachedFragment = new MyFragment(); //or whatever fragment you are trying to show
}

SupportFragmentManager
    .BeginTransaction()
    .SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.fab_slide_in_from_right, Resource.Animation.fab_slide_out_to_left)
    .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, cachedFragment, fragmentTag)
    .AddToBackStack(null) //this caches the fragment
    .Commit();
```